# How to delete all created localSharedObjects in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, cookies, local-shared-object

I'm working on a Flash website and would like to delete all localSharedObjects (aka Flash cookies) that got created from that SWF domain space. (basically it's the user session)
I found `mySharedObject.clear();`, but that function only deletes one localSharedObject and not all of the assigned domain.
How to delete them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to read all sharedObjects and then delete them.

```
sharedObject1 = SharedObject.getLocal("mySharedObject1");
sharedObject2 = SharedObject.getLocal("mySharedObject2");
...
sharedObject1.clear();
sharedObject2.clear();
...
```

I don't think that it is possible in any other way in flash.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The SharedObjects are bound to the domain where they got created. I thought there would be a way to clear/delete that domain.sol file.

Comment: @Tom Each shared object is stored in its own file, and `clear()` drops that file or its contents. So, if the domain has more than a single object defined in it, you have to read and clear them all, one by one.